# Can I use a PHP string Multiple Times

Tags: php

I was wondering if I could using a string multiple times in my php to do something like this:

```
$image = "Image One Here";
$title = "Title One Here";
$link = "Link One Here";

$image = "Image Two Here";
$title = "Title Two Here";
$link = "Link Two Here";

$image = "Image Three Here";
$title = "Title Three Here";
$link = "Link Three Here";


foreach(condition here) {
 echo $image;
 echo '<br/>';
 echo $title;
 echo '<br/>';
 echo $link;
}
```

Any idea on how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can try to use array

Comment: I've actually been trying an array, but havent really figured out how I would do it for this? Any example?

Comment: you want use 1 foreach to print out all output?

Comment: `$image = array("Image One Here", "Image Two Here", "Image Three Here");
$i = 0;
foreach(condition here) {
 echo $image[$i];
 $i++`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps,

```
    $image[] = "Image One Here";
    $title[] = "Title One Here";
    $link[] = "Link One Here";

    $image[] = "Image Two Here";
    $title[] = "Title Two Here";
    $link[] = "Link Two Here";

    $image[] = "Image Three Here";
    $title[] = "Title Three Here";
    $link[] = "Link Three Here";


    foreach($image as $key=>$img) {
        echo $img;
        echo '<br/>';
        echo $title[$key];
        echo '<br/>';
        echo $link[$key];
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This way you can do.

```
$image[] = array('Image one here','Image two here');
$title[] = array("Title One Here","Title Two Here");
$link[] = array("Link One Here","Link Two Here");

foreach($image as $value)
{
    echo $image[$value];
    echo $title[$value];
    echo $link[$value];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with `for` and `foreach`

```
$images = array('image1','image2','image3');
$titles = array('title','title2','title3');
$links = array('link1','link2','link3');

for($i=0; $i<count($images);$i++){
echo $images[i]. "<br/>" . $titles[i] . "<br/>" . $links[i]."</br>";
}
```

or with the foreach()

```
foreach($images as $key => $value){
echo $images[$key]. "<br/>" . $titles[$key] . "<br/>" . $links[$key]."</br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using array

```
$image=array('One','Two','Three');
$link=array('One','Two','Three');
$title=array('One','Two','Three');
foreach($title as $key)
{
    echo $image[$key].'<br/>';
    echo $link[$key].'<br/>';
    echo $title[$key].'<br/>';
}
```

Simple and short